# object-fit alternative for ie 11

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I have a image in a `div`. The image is set to fill the screen and scale from center with the following css

```
.backdiv img{
height:100%;
width: 100%;
display: block;
object-fit:cover;
```

}

Everything works fine on chrome/safari/firefox. On IE 11 the aspect ratio of the image is not maintained as the image is being forced to be 100% width and 100% and the `object-fit` is ignored since ie 11 does not support it.

How can i achieve the same on ie 11

Comment: the only interoperable way (IE9 emulation and higher) is to use the background style property of the containing div and to do away with the <img> child element.

Answer (score 0):

you can do away with the img element and style the background style of the containing div

```
<div id="divbackground" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;background-image:url(myimage.png);background-size:fill">
```

To make an img element render with its 'natural' aspect ratio, just specify its width or height style to 100%, not both... eg.

Answer (score 0):

This is old question, but I have had the exact same annoying issue where everything worked fine for Chrome/Edge but some css properties did not work in IE11,
I ended up using HTML "figure" element which solved all my problems.

The below code forces the image to reduce nicely(without changing the original aspect ratio).

```
<figure class="figure-class">

<img class="image-class" src="{{photoURL}}" />

</figure>
```

and css classes:

```
.image-class {
    border: 6px solid #E8E8E8;
    max-width: 189px;
    max-height: 189px;
}

.figure-class {
    width: 189px;
    height: 189px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently got the same issue and here is my solution:

```css
.backdiv {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.backdiv img {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

It looks exactly like `object-fit: cover;`. Image is centered by using flex layout, you can change image position by changing `justify-content` and `align-items`

Answer (score 0):

```
if ('objectFit' in document.documentElement.style === false) {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        document.querySelectorAll("img").forEach(function (image) {
            if (image.currentStyle['object-position'] || image.currentStyle['object-fit']) {
                (image.runtimeStyle || image.style).background = "url(\"".concat(image.src, "\") no-repeat ");
                if (image.currentStyle['object-fit'])
                    (image.runtimeStyle || image.style).backgroundSize = image.currentStyle['object-fit'];
                if (image.currentStyle['object-position'])
                    (image.runtimeStyle || image.style).backgroundPosition = image.currentStyle['object-position'];
                image.src = "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='".concat(image.width, "' height='").concat(image.height, "'%3E%3C/svg%3E");
            }
        });
    });
}
```

here is a work around to find all the images that have object-fit and object-position for ie